# Ignore failing future in for comprehension

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I have a for comprehension of futures that all make remote service calls (REST, RPC, etc...). If one of those future fails, will the entire for comprehension fail?

For instance, let's say I have two futures that make service calls

```
val service1Future: Future[Response] = ...
val service2Future: Future[Response] = ...
```

Let's say service2Future also has some `recoverWith` that throws an exception `PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[U]]`.

If service2Future fails, I don't really care. Can I enforce that in my for comprehension?

```
for {
    service1Response <- service1Future
    service2Response <- service2Future
} yield {
    // do stuff with service1Response, but I want to get here even if service2Future fails
}
```

Comment: So using for comprehension or flatMap makes no sense in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the entire for-comprehension will fail if the second future fails as written. Would something as simple as this work?

```
for {
  service1Response <- service1Future
  service2Response <- service2Future.recoverWith(...)
} yield {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is this necessary if `def getService2: Future[Result] = {
...code...
someFutureCall.recoverWith(...)
}` (i.e. the method returning service2Future already has a recoverWith inside of it)?

Comment: If it already has a `recoverWith`, and the function passed to `recoverWith` cannot fail, then this is not necessary and the basic for-comprehension in your initial answer will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to return `Future[Try[Response]]` instead of `Future[Response]`. In `recoverWith` you would return `Future(Failure(e))`. You can then pattern match in the `yield` to see if it was successful or not.